# Using CSS only to slow off hover

Tags: css

I have the following CSS and want to slow the displayLnone attribute when it goes off hover but the transitions don't seem to be working.

CSS:

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: -15px;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;

    list-style: none; 
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid #759931;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    z-index:10000;
    -webkit-transition: all 5000ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 5000ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 5000ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 5000ms ease;
    transition: all 5000ms ease;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu
{
    display: block;
}
```

A JSFiddle would be helpful.

Comment: `display` cannot be transitioned or animated. Use `opacity` or `transform: scale()` according to your likings.

Comment: transition will work only with values that can be divide or multiplicated, display is not an option, opacity could do it ... so is height or max-height or any other rules with numeric values

Comment: how do I do it with opacity? just curious

Comment: basicly : opacity:0; then opacity:1; on hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display` cannot be transitioned or animated. Use `opacity` or `transform: scale()` according to your likings. Here's an example using `opacity`:

```css
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  left: -15px;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #759931;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 10000;
  -webkit-transition: all 5000ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 5000ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 5000ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 5000ms ease;
  transition: all 5000ms ease;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* demo styles */
.dropdown {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">Hover me
  <div class="dropdown-menu">My beautiful menu</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`transition` and `animate` only work on certain properties (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties ). You have to use height/width, opacity, etc.

It should also be noted, if using `height` or `width`, the keyword `auto` cannot be transitioned to or from.

Edit:

```css
li>ul.height {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li:hover>ul.height {
  max-height: 200px;
}

li>ul.opacity {
  opacity: 0;
}

li:hover>ul.opacity {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Basic Stuff */

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: .5em;
}

li>ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: all ease 2s;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Sublist Height
      <ul class="height">
        <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Sublist Opacity
      <ul class="opacity">
        <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.dropdown {
  padding: 5px;
  background: tomato;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid peru;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  Hover
  <div class="dropdown-menu">Menu</div>
</div>
```

Key bits are `opacity: 0` and `visibility: hidden`, and then `opacity: 1` and `visibility: visible` on hover. That will create the transition/fade-in look you're going for.

Comment: why visibility ? no need and it is not compatible with transtion nor animation ..;) (pointer-events seems more accurate somehow )

Answer (score 0):

The `display` property is not animatable. You can read the list of animatable properties (which translates to: properties that can be used transitions/animations) right here: [CSS Animatable](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_animatable.asp)